# How do I pass an array to a MongoRepository @Query?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

Using Spring Data MongoDB. And I have defined this query on my MongoRepository:

```
@Query("{'type':?0, 'tags.type':?1, 'tags.softSkill.name': {$all: ?2}}")
List<Foo> findByTypeAndTags_TypeAndTags_SoftSkills(
        FooType type, TagType tagType, String[] softSkills);
```

As I want to use `$all` operator I can't build the query through the method-naming way so I use the `@Query` annotation.

The issue is that it doesn't like the `String[]` that I try to pass for `?2` argument. I've tried with a List but the the error remains.

```
value expected to be of type java.util.List but is class java.lang.String toString:fooStr
```

On a mongo-shell would be like: `$all: ['foo1','foo2']`

**Foo** abstract entity is like:

```
@Data
@Document(collection="foes")
public abstract class Foo {
    /*...*/ 
    protected List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Tag** asbtract pojo:

```
@Data
public abstract class Tag {

    protected final TagType type;
    protected TagLevel level;

}
```

**TagSoftSkill** pojo:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
public class TagSoftSkill extends Tag{

    private SoftSkill softSkill;  //another pojo that has a "name" field


    public TagSoftSkill() {
        super(TagType.SOFT_SKILL);
    }


}
```

I already debugged and `softSkills` prints `[foo]`. I modified the value to be like `['foo']` but there are no changes.

Comment: Can you show us the sample calling method with input arg `softSkills` that is failing  and please add your `Foo` bean to the post as well ?

Comment: @Veeram ok, done

Comment: I can`t recreate the error. Both the lists and array works for me with your set up in 1.10.4 spring mongo release. Can you add the stacktrace for the exception ?

Comment: @Veeram So doing a `@Query` with `{$all: ?2}` and passing a `String[]` should be legit? Ok, I will continue debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't mention that I'm using [fongo](https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo). Switched to real mongo and everything works as it should. So it's a fongo issue.